# Multiple arguments in mouseover - d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been experimenting with tooltips in `d3.js` but am struggling to get it to behave accurately.

This is my `div.tooltip`:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

And here is my function, where I am trying to plot some data points. x-axis is `date` and y-axis is `price`.  The data are colored by `symbol`.    When hovering over each point, I am trying to get the data point to enlarge its color and fill with its color.  This is working fine.    I also want a little textbox to float to the top-right of it with information about the date/price.  For some reason, this is appearing at the bottom left of my chart underneath the x-axis for every data point.   As shown below:

```
// Add some datapoints
        svg.selectAll("dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 1.5)
             .style("fill", "white")    
             .style("opacity", .8)  
             .style("stroke-width", 1) 
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.symbol); })

            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.symbol); });

               div.transition()     
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      

             div.html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.price)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px");    


            })
```

e.g. When I hover over this green point, it enlarges and fills, but the textbox appears in the bottom left with no text?

[image]

Comment: Have you established a positioning context?

Comment: @CoolBlue - no, I don't think so.  How should I do that?  I have posted full code at this gist - https://gist.github.com/jalapic/5e99a382077c53ac5e53 - Thanks.

Comment: I actually think I have solved this - it was because I had failed to define the `formatTime` function in my `div.html` - embarrassing.!

Comment: Probably best if you wrap your svg in a div, say it's called viz and has id viz, then add `#viz {position:relative}` to your CSS. append the tooltip on viz and access the relative position of the mouse with `d3.mouse(viz)` to get x and y in your event handler. Maybe you have to use `d3.mouse(viz.node())`, I'm not sure...